# SMS Retriever API android system unable to send message to the Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, kotlin, sms

I have been trying to implement [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify) to collect incoming sms from the server on the phone, apparently `onReceive()` on the broadcast listener is never called when sms is received on the phone.

**Client implementation** is mentioned as below.

```
    private fun startSMSListener() {
    Log.d(TAG, "startSMSListener():")

    val client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this)
    val retriever = client.startSmsRetriever()
    retriever.addOnSuccessListener {

        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Listener started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val otpListener = object : SMSBroadcastReceiver.OTPListener {
            override fun onOTPReceived(otp: String) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onOTPReceived(): $otp")
                tv_hash_code.text = otp
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, otp , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onOTPTimeOut() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onOTPTimeOut():")
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"TimeOut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        //smsBroadcastReceiver this is already initialized 
        smsBroadcastReceiver.injectOTPListener(otpListener)
        registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver,
            IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION))
    }
    retriever.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Problem to start listener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Broadcast receiver is

```
class SMSBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {


private var otpReceiver: OTPListener? = null

fun injectOTPListener(receiver: OTPListener?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "injectOTPListener is empty : ${receiver == null}")
    this.otpReceiver = receiver
}

override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, intent.action)
    if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION == intent.action) {
        val extras = intent.extras
        val status = extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS) as Status

        when (status.statusCode) {

            CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS")
                Toast.makeText(context, "CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                val message = extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE) as String

                val pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{6}")
                val matcher = pattern.matcher(message)

                if (matcher.find()) {
                    otpReceiver?.onOTPReceived(matcher.group(0))
                    return
                }
            }
            CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT -> {
                Log.d(TAG, "CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT")
                Toast.makeText(context, "CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                otpReceiver?.onOTPTimeOut()
            }
        }
    }
}

interface OTPListener {


    fun onOTPReceived(otp: String)

    fun onOTPTimeOut()
}
}
```

**Server Implementation**

This is what I have for the message

```
<#> Your SmsVerificationCOde code is: 123456
wPMABADKiiS
```

This Hash-Code generated using debug key, I tried three different methods to generate the hash-code which all provide the same value.

1. Keytool

   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore  ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.smsverificationcode `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
2. [Script](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/bin/sms_retriever_hash_v9.sh)

   ./sms_retriever_hash_v9.sh --package "com.example.smsverificationcode" --keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
3. [AppSignatureHelper](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/sms-verification/android/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/smartlock/sms_verify/AppSignatureHelper.java)

all of them seem to provide the same hash-code which makes me believe that hash-code is alright ( I tried this for release type any way, all method provide me with another "value" which is same for all method of evaluation )

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify
https://medium.com/@wilderpereira/secure-android-otp-account-verification-with-the-sms-retriever-api-c395c1985fbf

I am positive the client implementation is correct as I get the TimeOut error after 5 minutes, but never actually get anything at time of sms arrival.

I believe that Android system is not able to figure out the my application based of the hash-code or the format of my message could be wrong.

Kindly have a look and correct me where I could be wrong. any help is highly regarded.

Comment: This is not a question that contains java..

Comment: @CagriYalcin, corrected

Answer (score 1):

You **must** register the broadcast receiver in the manifest for global broadcasts. SMS_RETRIEVER is a global broadcast. Your broadcast receiver cannot be dynamic in this case.

Please see the following link for the solution you're looking for: https://medium.com/@wilderpereira/secure-android-otp-account-verification-with-the-sms-retriever-api-c395c1985fbf

Answer (score 0):

You're only registering you **Broadcast Receiver** after you start your `SmsRetriever`.

The Broadcast Receiver should already be registered when you initialize the `SmsRetriever`

After making the changes, your code should look something like this:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        val smsBroadcastReceiver = SMSBroadcastReceiver()

        val otpListener = object : SMSBroadcastReceiver.OTPListener {
            override fun onOTPReceived(otp: String) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, otp , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onOTPTimeOut() {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"TimeOut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }

        smsBroadcastReceiver.injectOTPListener(otpListener)
        registerReceiver(smsBroadcastReceiver,
                IntentFilter(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION))

        startSMSListener()

   }

    private fun startSMSListener() {
        Log.d("CodeVerification", "startSMSListener()")

        val client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this)
        val retriever = client.startSmsRetriever()
        retriever.addOnSuccessListener {

            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Listener started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

        retriever.addOnFailureListener {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Problem to start listener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

I used your code with those changes and it worked fine!

Also, make sure you're using the correct Keystore to sign the APK.

If you want to make sure you're using the correct debug keystore, you can add the following to you **build.gradle** file.

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file(<path to debug keystore>)
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
        }
    }
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you WIlder, let me try this out. I can't comment that's why I couldn't reach you

Comment: So making changes didn't help,

I am calling 'startSMSListener()'  on a button click to make sure I start broadcast receiver just before sending the message

you can look up at this, https://github.com/pankajnimgade/ConfigureBuilds/blob/master/app/src/miscellaneous/java/configure/test/configurebuilds/activities/test101/SmsRetrieverTest101Activity.kt

this is little confusing

Comment: In the code you linked you are still initializing the Broadcast Receiver after you initialize the sms listener.

Comment: I tried instantiating broadcast receiver first as well, I believe that this is more related formatting of my message, if you could check that for me